# Netbeans: How to hide status bar?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

In the bottom of Neatbeans there's a bar that in browsers is called "status bar".
Is it possible to hide it? I can't find a way to do it by removing items from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an old way, but it works (NetBeans 8.2).

Go to `{Netbeans directory}/etc/netbeans.conf`

...find line: `netbeans_default_options`

and append this string to it: `-J-Dnetbeans.winsys.statusLine.in.menuBar=true`

So the whole will line could look like this:
`netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms1024m -J-Xmx2096m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dnetbeans.winsys.statusLine.in.menuBar=true"`

Now the status bar is at the top and you have 1cm space more! :-)